# What is the fastest way to update SQL rows with values, based upon a value in the row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, foreach, sql-update

I have the following `table` in `SQL Server` called `tblProducts`:

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| pkProduct | fkProductID  |  intIssue   |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|     1     |     10       |      1      |
|     2     |     10       |      2      |
|     3     |     10       |      4      |
|     4     |     11       |      1      |
|     5     |     11       |      2      |
|     6     |     11       |      3      |
|     7     |     11       |      5      |
|     8     |     12       |      1      |
|     9     |     13       |      1      |
|     10    |     13       |      4      |
|     11    |     14       |      1      |
|     12    |     14       |      3      |
|     13    |     14       |      6      |
|     14    |     15       |      1      |
|     15    |     16       |      1      |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

Over time, with rows having being deleted for whatever reasons, there are now gaps in the issue numbers. I would like the issue numbers to run in order so as the `table` looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| pkProduct | fkProductID  |  intIssue   |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|     1     |     10       |      1      |
|     2     |     10       |      2      |
|     3     |     10       |      3      |
|     4     |     11       |      1      |
|     5     |     11       |      2      |
|     6     |     11       |      3      |
|     7     |     11       |      4      |
|     8     |     12       |      1      |
|     9     |     13       |      1      |
|     10    |     13       |      2      |
|     11    |     14       |      1      |
|     12    |     14       |      2      |
|     13    |     14       |      3      |
|     14    |     15       |      1      |
|     15    |     16       |      1      |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

At the moment I have added the `table` to my `DataSet` and using this in `vb.net` code i update the rows:

```vb
Dim currentProductsTable As tblProductsDataTable

Using taProduct As New tblProductsTableAdapter
    currentProductsTable = taProduct.GetData
End Using

Dim issueCounter As Integer = 1
Dim previousRow As tblProductsRow = Nothing

Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.tblProducts SET [intIssue] = @issueCounter WHERE pkProduct = @ProductID", con)
        cmd.Connection = con 
        con.Open()
        For Each row As tblProductsRow In currentProductsTable.Rows
            If Not previousRow Is Nothing Then
                If row.fkProductID = previousRow.fkProductID Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@issueCounter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issueCounter
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.pkProduct
                    previousRow = row
                Else
                    issueCounter = 1
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@issueCounter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issueCounter
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.pkProduct
                    previousRow = row
                End If
            Else
                issueCounter = 1
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@issueCounter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issueCounter
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.pkProduct
                previousRow = row
            End If
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            issueCounter += 1
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

I have ordered the `.GetData` by `fkProductID ASC`, and `intIssue ASC`,
but it takes a very long time as there are around 30000 `rows` in the `table`.

I wondered if there was a faster way to do this kind of updating?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Tagged, what a wally! sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to guess that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can do this all in one query:

```
with toupdate as (
      select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fkProductID order by pkProduct) as new_intIssue
      from dbo.tblProducts p
     )
update toupdate
    set intIssue = new_intIssue
    where intIssue <> new_intIssue;
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to of worked perfectly on a quick scan of the rows. I really need to learn more SQL. The query completed in less than a second! Compared to the 10 + minutes doing it within the loop. It's pretty amazing how quick you answer aswell, but i guess if you know then it's easy! I'm still amazed though.

Comment: @Pete . . . I've had a bit of experience learning how people use databases and the things that need to be done.