# Is the an SQL squery I can use to fix my issue numbers that have gone out of order?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030582) I have asked only this time with minor issue numbers.

I am wondering how I can correct this table:

```
 +-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
 | pkProduct | fkProductID  |intMajorIssue|intMinorIssue|
 +-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
 |     1     |     10       |      1      |      0      |
 |     2     |     10       |      2      |      0      |
 |     3     |     10       |      2      |      1      |
 |     4     |     10       |      2      |      1      |
 |     5     |     10       |      2      |      2      |
 |     6     |     11       |      1      |      0      |
 |     7     |     11       |      1      |      1      |
 |     8     |     11       |      1      |      1      |
 |     9     |     11       |      1      |      1      |
 |     10    |     11       |      2      |      0      |
 |     11    |     11       |      2      |      1      |
 |     12    |     12       |      1      |      0      |
 |     13    |     12       |      2      |      1      |
 +-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+`
```

To look like this:

```
 +-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
 | pkProduct | fkProductID  |intMajorIssue|intMinorIssue|
 +-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
 |     1     |     10       |      1      |      0      |
 |     2     |     10       |      2      |      0      |
 |     3     |     10       |      2      |      1      |
 |     4     |     10       |      2      |      2      |
 |     5     |     10       |      2      |      3      |
 |     6     |     11       |      1      |      0      |
 |     7     |     11       |      1      |      1      |
 |     8     |     11       |      1      |      2      |
 |     9     |     11       |      1      |      3      |
 |     10    |     11       |      2      |      0      |
 |     11    |     11       |      2      |      1      |
 |     12    |     12       |      1      |      0      |
 |     13    |     12       |      2      |      0      |
 +-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+`
```

Basically I need to fix the minor issue numbers so that they run in order for each product.

I have been trying to amend the answer I was given on the previous question to do this but so far having no luck.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Gordon's answer to your last question should get you pretty close. Post the code that you've tried, and the results that weren't quite right, and we'll get you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by fkProductID, intMajorIssue order by pkProduct) rn
  from tablename  
)
update cte
set intMinorIssue = rn - 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93de5e7645902c6b5c1d99ebb4c6ad16).
Results:

```
> pkProduct | fkProductID | intMajorIssue | intMinorIssue
> --------: | ----------: | ------------: | ------------:
>         1 |          10 |             1 |             0
>         2 |          10 |             2 |             0
>         3 |          10 |             2 |             1
>         4 |          10 |             2 |             2
>         5 |          10 |             2 |             3
>         6 |          11 |             1 |             0
>         7 |          11 |             1 |             1
>         8 |          11 |             1 |             2
>         9 |          11 |             1 |             3
>        10 |          11 |             2 |             0
>        11 |          11 |             2 |             1
>        12 |          12 |             1 |             0
>        13 |          12 |             2 |             0
```